# Redirect and mask URL but leave query parameters (Apache or htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, server, network-programming

So I have a domain

```
example.com
```

and I have some content on another domain which is under port different than 80

```
example2.com:8080
```

When a user enters `example.com/parameter` he should get content from `example2.com:8080/parameter` and in the address bar there should be
`example.com/parameter`.

Is this possible with apache?

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: @miramarska In what way does the linked question not solve your problem? Do you get an error? An incorrect request? The solution(s) presented in the linked question would seem to be what you would need to do, ie. configure `example.com` as a _reverse proxy_ in your Apache config/`.htaccess`. (Or configure the server at `example2.com:8080` to accept requests to both hosts - as suggested in the non-accepted answer on the linked question.)